# Asterisk 10, dahdi_dummy won't build

Tags: module, asterisk

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.0-2-amd64 (Debian 3.2.12-1) (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-1) ) #1 SMP Tue Mar 20 18:36:37 UTC 2012
```

I've read some apps in Asterisk 10 still use timers from dahdi_dummy. But it won't build - make ignores dahdi_dummy module:

```
root@ster:/usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.0+2.6.0# find ./ -name '*dummy*'
./tools/menuselect/contrib/Makefile-dummy
./tools/menuselect/contrib/menuselect-dummy
./linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi_dummy.c
```

`dahdi show status` in cli shows nothing. Really i will not use digium cards, so i *probably* need only dahdi_dummy.

```
# lsmod | grep dahdi
dahdi_transcode        13001  1 wctc4xxp
dahdi_voicebus         45931  2 wcte12xp,wctdm24xxp
dahdi                 191058  11     wct4xxp,dahdi_voicebus,wcte12xp,wct1xxp,wcte11xp,wctdm24xxp,wcfxo,wctdm,wcb4xxp,dahdi_transcode,xpp
crc_ccitt              12347  2 dahdi,wctdm24xxp
```

So, may be i don't need that module anymore? And why it won't compile?

Thanks.

Comment: `make MODULES_EXTRA="dahdi_dummy"` [fails here](https://issues.asterisk.org/view.php?id=17959)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need dahdi_dummy anymore. It has not been required since DAHDI-Linux 2.3.0. The core of DAHDI is now able to use the kernel timers automatically if no telephony hardware is installed.

The reason it won't compile in 2.6.0 was due to an error that was fixed in 2.6.0-rc1. The interface between the core of DAHDI and the board drivers changed but dahdi_dummy was not updated as well. More information is available on the Asterisk issue tracker in issue [DAHLIN-274](https://issues.asterisk.org/jira/browse/DAHLIN-274).